# Sqlite3 on PowerCMD or Console2

Tags: windows, cmd, sqlite

I successfully installed Sqlite3 on my machine by downloading the precompiled binaries for Sqlite3 and moving them to C:\Windows\System32. I can run the command sqlite3 from the windows command prompt with no issues.

However, I want to move to one of the alternatives of the windows command prompt.
I have tried PowerCMD and Console2.

Both of them fail to run the sqlite3 command and display the following message:

'sqlite3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.

Comment: Seems to be a path issue; perhaps the `%PATH%` variable is not regarded? try to provide full path to `sqlite3` executable;

Comment: It is added @aschipfl , else it would not have worked on the windows command prompt. The Sqlite3 files are copied in the `System32` folder, which is added in the `%PATH%` variable.